# Why user who is defined inside the Access Request can not approve pending access requests

Tags: sharepoint-online, administration, access-requests

We have a modern team site and inside the access request we define a user, as follow:-

[image]

now this users is defined inside the related office 365 group members, and he have a Member role, as follow:-

[image]

Now the user will receive access requests, but when the user try to approve/reject the requests the user will get Access Denied Error? any advice ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to this [Microsoft article](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/office/set-up-and-manage-access-requests-94b26e0b-2822-49d4-929a-8455698654b3),

> A site owner can then approve or decline the request, or specify the
> permission level to be assigned to the new user.

The specific user should be the owner role.